# Positioning a box in an AR scene view with the same coordinates as an AR plane

Tags: position, augmented-reality, plane

I am trying to position a box in an AR view and I need it to be at the same position as my AR Plane, or where the Plane Anchor is detected. My code is trying to call to the addBoxEToPlane func so that I can position BoxE the same as the plane, but it gives me the error "Value of tuple type '()' has no member 'position' ". If anybody can help me call to that function, or basically position that box the same as the AR Plane, I would really appreciate it!

```
func addBoxEToPlane(){

    let boxE = SCNNode(geometry: SCNBox(width: 2.0, height: 2.0, length: 2.0, chamferRadius: 0))
    boxE.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
}

func updateWith(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor) {

    plane.width  = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
    plane.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)

    position = SCNVector3Make(anchor.center.x, 0, anchor.center.z)

    if let grid = plane.materials.first as? GridMaterial {
        grid.updateWith(anchor: anchor)
    }
    let XCoord = (plane.width)/2
    let YCoord = (plane.height)/2

    addBoxEToPlane().position = SCNVector3(XCoord, YCoord, anchor.center.z)

}
```